# Disable a cell based on input using Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

how to disable a particular cell based on  input using google apps script.

We are using following code

```
    function Lock_Cells() 
   {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    for (var i = 12; i <= 13; i++)
    {
    var Check_Cell = "H" + i;
    var Temp = sheet.getRange(Check_Cell).getValue();
    if (Temp == "YES")
    {

    var Lock_Range = sheet.getRange("H" + i + ":J" + i);

    var protection = Lock_Range.protect().setDescription('Sample protected      range');


     var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
     protection.addEditor(me);
     protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
     if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
     protection.setDomainEdit(false);
     }
     }
     }  
}
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

From your code I am assuming you are using this [link](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2015/02/control-protected-ranges-and-sheets-in.html) for reference to your script. In case you need to protect a certain range based off the response of 1 (or more) columns, here is a sample I just used and tested:

```
function onEdit()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = range.getValues();

  var response = "";

  var aCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var aRow = aCell.getRow();
  var aCol = aCell.getColumn();

  sheet.getRange(aRow, 2).protect();

  response = data[aRow-1][0];

  if (aCol == 1 && response == "Book")
  {
    sheet.getRange(aRow, 2).canEdit();
  }else{
    sheet.getRange(aRow, 2).setValue("--NA--");
  }

}
```

This is a slightly different approach that I used for one of my sheets as well. Here, instead of taking away the permission based on their entry I am giving them permission based on their response in Column 1 using the [canEdit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#canEdit()) function. This not only will make sure your invalid fields are protected but will also make sure they enter the data without discrepancies like Spelling mistakes. So, if someone was to enter "bok" instead of "Book" this will not work.

However, using the onEdit function ensures even the changes made by owner to column 2 will be reverted back to --NA-- if column 1 says anything but "Book".